# Make added geometry using geometry node relate to instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm experimenting in Geometry Nodes and I'm making a mace/spike club thing. Right now I've added a collection of spikes as instances and then a handle right onto the geometry that i've moved and rotated.

I've made sure the spikes has a Min Distance so that they don't overlap. Is there any way I can add this attribute so that the spikes do not overlap on the handle, too?

[image: Screenshot of mace]

[image]

EDIT:

I've managed to make them relate to each other like this. Unfortunately this also adds spikes to the handle.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The _Distribute Points on Faces_ as well as the _Instance on Points_ nodes both have _Selection_ inputs. Why not create a vertex group excluding those vertices which are close to the handle and use that as a selection in one of those nodes?

Comment: Sounds like what I want to accomplish, yeah. How do I go about this? I've created a vertex group, added the selection input to the object node and selected the vertex group. I tried both density factor and selection but no luck. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcEJT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvuCU.png

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Forgot to weight paint. :- ) Thanks! This worked nicely

Comment: Okay, I didn't actually weight paint... I just made a new vertex group, selected the vertices outside the handle and assigned them to the group. Okay, in weight paint mode this is shown as painted with 1, but painting is not needed ;) And I don't know if this is additional help that you put it in the Density as well, but it shouldn't be necessary. Or I guess you can either use one or the other.

Comment: I didn't get that to work but I will experiment with it. I wonder if there is a solution that is connected to the position of the handle in this position? Like, if i were to move or rotate the handle, the "vertex group" moves along with it? It's not necessary in this case but it made me curious.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think earlier of that. I'll make an answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To spare certain areas close to the handle from getting spikes, you can use the *Geometry Proximity* node together with a *Greater Than* node. Plug the geometry of the handle into the *Target* input and the *Distance* output into the *Greater Than* node. The *Threshold* value should be adjusted until no spikes are too close to the handle. The output of the *Math* node can be used in one of the *Selection* inputs.

[image: geometry proximity]

The default option of the *Geometry Proximity* node is using *Faces*, you can change this to *Edges* or *Points*. If you e.g. plug a *Distribute Points on Faces* node between the handle geometry and the proximity check, you can use the density and distribution of those points to measure the distance to the other geometry.

In your case this might not be necessary, but maybe in other scenarios maybe the face resolution might not be high enough or whatever and then you could distribute points on them with a very high density for example.

Comment: The only thing is, as far as I know the handle can be an external object adressed by an _Object Info_ node to be plugged to the _Target_ input of the _Geometry Proximity_ node. But the _Distance_ is always calculated in relation to the original mesh which is the one from the _Group Input_, the one you see when you switch to _Edit Mode_. I have no idea if there is a posiibility to use any other external geometry or a GN internal mesh primitive.

Comment: @BingoBango Seems like the _Distance_ is not necessarily calculated to the original mesh but some GN mesh primitive can be used as well. Just found that out.